# Look up elements in a generic tree

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I have a json nested object, similar to [this](https://raw.github.com/mbostock/d3/master/examples/data/flare.json).

In my case, I have a  unique `id` field of type int(say instead `name` above). This is not a binary tree, but more depict parent-child relationship. I wanted a way to easy lookup the child tree (children) rooted at say `id = 121`.  In a brute force way, I may compare all nodes till I find one, and return the children. But I was think of keeping a map of {id, node}. For example `{"121" : root[1][10]..[1]}`. This may be super wastefulness of memory (unless use a pointer to the array).Note sure any better way.

I have control over what to send from server, so may augment above data structure. but need a quick way to get child tree based on node id in the client side.

EDIT:
I am considering keeping another data structure, map of {id, []ids}, where ids is the ordered path from root. Any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in javascript are true pointer-based objects, meaning that you can keep multiple references to them without using much more memory. Why not do a single traversal to assign the sub-objects to a new id-based parent object? Unless your hierarchical object is simply enormous, this should be very fast.

In light of best practice and what would happen if the application you're building were to scale to millions of users, you might rethink whether you really want the server to do more work. The client's computer is sitting there, ready to provide you with remote computing power for FREE. Why move the work load to the server causing it to process fewer client requests per second? That may not be a direction you want to go.

[Here is a fiddle demonstrating this index-building technique](http://jsfiddle.net/PSKrz/2/). You run through it once, and use the index over and over as you please. It only takes 4 or 5 ms to build said index. There is no performance problem!

One more note: if you are concerned with bandwith, one simple way to help with that is trim down your JSON. Don't put quotes around object key names, use one-letter key names, and don't use whitespace and line breaks. That will get you a very large improvement. Performing this change to your example JSON, it goes from 11,792 characters to 5,770, only 49% of the original size!

One minor note is that object keys in javascript are always Strings. The numeric ids I added to your example JSON are coerced to strings when used as a key name. This should be no impediment to usage, but it is a subtle difference that you may want to be aware of.

Comment: I agree with your argument. I have an opportunity to build the index at the server while populating the tree, still your approach might be better considering extra bandwidth. The key misunderstanding was I wasn't sure the assignment like index[obj.id] = obj; would not create a new obj rather than refer to obj.

Comment: I updated my fiddle to display a preview of the index and also to show the elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't assume that the ids are somehow ordered, but still it might help to prune at least parts of the tree if you add to each node the information about the **minimum and maximum id** value of its children (and sub... children).

This can be quite easily be achieved at server side and when searching the tree you can check if the id you're looking for is within the id-range of a node, before stepping inside and searching all children.